# How to replace an index with an Array of image URL's in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, opencv, indexing

I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/12/01/complete-guide-building-image-search-engine-python-opencv/) online to create a reverse image search engine, however, I do not want to search an index of images, but only an array of image URL's, that I will be retrieving in JSON (I will only be searching 10 images, which will all be closely related). I am currently looking into the best way to create this array, but I do not know how I can replace the index with just a simple array that is looped over, to compare the initial image being used in the search, with the ones in the array. The index class from the tutorial is below:

```
# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True,
                help="Path to the directory that contains the images to be indexed")
ap.add_argument("-i", "--index", required=True,
                help="Path to where the computed index will be stored")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# initialize the color descriptor
cd = ColorDescriptor((8, 12, 3))

# open the output index file for writing
output = open(args["index"], "w")

# use glob to grab the image paths and loop over them
for imagePath in glob.glob(args["dataset"] + "/*.png"):
    # extract the image ID (i.e. the unique filename) from the image
    # path and load the image itself
    imageID = imagePath[imagePath.rfind("/") + 1:]
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)

    # describe the image
    features = cd.describe(image)

    # write the features to file
    features = [str(f) for f in features]
    output.write("%s,%s\n" % (imageID, ",".join(features)))

# close the index file
output.close()
```

I am going to eventually be outputting the result of the search in JSON form also, to add a GUI for the system. Thank you.

P.S. I am fairly new to python and I'm still not too familiar with how some concepts work in this language.

Answer (score 1):

This would look something like

```
image_list = [
  "http://www.photo_location1.com/local_dir/photo_name1.png",
  "http://www.photo_location2.com/local_dir/photo_name2.png",
  ...
]

for imagePath in image_list:
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
```

... and continue as you're already doing.

Comment: So would this replace: # open the output index file for writing
output = open(args["index"], "w") ? I'm not too sure how I would be replacing this function?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, yes: this code merely replaces your input-derived index with a list of URLs.